# Where does pip install packages from?

Tags: python, pip

I need to download the Biopython package using pip. I ran `pip install biopython` but got the following error:

[image]

I verified that the problem is because the network blocks most sites by trying to install other packages (through pip and other means) and getting a network connection error. To allow these downloads, I need to compile the list of urls of the source of the downloads and send it to the network admins to unblock.

According to pip documentation (cited and explained in brief in the pip Wikipedia article), “Many packages can be found in the default source for packages and their dependencies — Python Package Index (PyPI)," so I went to the PyPI page for Biopython and found the github repository and the required dependencies for the package. There are also download links on the PyPI page and I want to be sure that all sources for the download are allowed. So does pip install from the original source of a package (the github repository or wherever the original package is hosted), the packages listed in the PyPI page under downloads, or does it search through both?

Comment: Error 101 from pip, which mostly means you're working behind a proxy server. Have a look at this method, manual installation : 
http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.html#htoc7

Comment: I am working on a server running RHEL and already have python2 and python34 installed (and also pip for the respective python versions). I also saw the ways to install using tar but will not be using that as it requires patching and resolving dependency issues later on. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is installing the packages from PyPi, yes.
On the PyPi website you can find links to github where you can find the full package code, but where `pip` download is PyPi.

Comment: I can sucessfully install `pygobject==3.26.1` in Docker Ubuntu 18.04 (`FROM ubuntu:bionic-20200903`).

BUT I cannot install it on Docker Ubuntu 20.04 (`FROM ubuntu:focal-20210921`). It says: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygobject==3.26.1`.

There is no `pygobject==3.26.1` on PyPi right now (I've checked manually on the site). So where does pip find this version when it is running on Ubuntu 18.04?

BTW I use `pip3`.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to have a machine with the same OS & Python that is outside of the network, in a clean directory run `python -m pip3 download biopython --dest .` this will download the appropriate packages **and** the packages that they depend on.

You can then, *after getting any required permissions & virus scans*, copy those files to your firewalled machine and `pip install <the files you downloaded>`

Alternatively, if you just want to find out all of the URLs involved then using *(again from a machine outside of your firewalled network running the same python version on the same OS)* you can capture the output of:
`python -m pip3 download -v -v biopython --dest .` this will show you **all** of the locations that are contacted during a download of the package and it's depenencies.